# How to set file pointer using seek in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to read a file and set a pointer 'P' at the end of the file so that next time when I will open that file again I can start reading from next to the pointer 'P'.

```
my $file = "/x/y/z.txt";
open (fh, "+<", "$file"); 
while(<fh>)
{
    push(@file, "$_");
}
my $saved_position = tell(fh);
my $x=seek($fh, $saved_position, 0);
```

Here, how to check at which position pointer is set so that I can read lines next to the pointer.

This can be a simple question or may be I am doing any simple mistake but I am stuck here badly, so please help me if anyone can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` could be beneficial for above code. Is there something wrong with `$saved_position`?

Comment: The "pointer" is part of the file handle, not the file. It's returned by `tell`. Feel free to save that value in file if you need it later.

Comment: You use the bare filehandle `fh` through most of the example but you refer to the scalar `$fh` in the last line, which is not the same thing.